# How to return data in foreach loop having multiple async functions inside

Tags: node.js, async-await

I am calling this function using await and store the data in the result variable. But the function returns without completing the foreach loop. How can I make this function return only if the foreach loop ends?

```
let result = await prepareStocks(data);

async function prepareStocks(incomingStocks) { 
    var stockCodes = incomingStocks.stocks.split(',');
    var stockPrices = incomingStocks.trigger_prices.split(',');
    var alertName = incomingStocks.alert_name;
    stockCodes.forEach(async(stocks, index) => {

        if (stockPrices[index] > 100) {

            var stockCodes = {
                code: stocks,
                price: stockPrices[index],
                orderType: (urls.buy.includes(alertName) ? 'BUY' : 'WATCH'),
                target: await setSellPrice(stockPrices[index], 1),
                stopLoss: await setStopLoss(stockPrices[index], 1),
            }
            STOCKS.push(stockCodes);
        }

    });
    return STOCKS;

}
```

Comment: If you want a return then use `.map()` -- `.forEach()` never returns anything.

Comment: Is it a requirement to name multiple variables as `stockCodes`? There is this: `var stockCodes = incomingStocks.stocks.split(',');` and then within the `stockCodes.forEach` there is this: `var stockCodes = {.....`. Both declarations are not block-scoped either. Please consider renaming either one. And, also please consider using `let` and `const` where it is appropriate (in lieu of `var`).

Comment: Do NOT use `.forEach()` with an `async` callback!  Never do it.  You have no control over anything.  Use a plain `for` and then you can control things.  `.forEach()` should be considered obsolete for any asynchronous coding.  You have no flow of control at all.  You can't return, you can't break, you can't do anything with the promise from the `async` callback.  Don't use `.forEach()` for async programming.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `Promise.all`

Something like this =>

```
let result = await prepareStocks(data);
async function prepareStocks(incomingStocks) { 
    var stockCodes = incomingStocks.stocks.split(',');
    var stockPrices = incomingStocks.trigger_prices.split(',');
    var alertName = incomingStocks.alert_name;


    const STOCKS = await Promise.all(stockCodes.map(async (stocks, index) => {
        if (stockPrices[index] > 100) {

            var stockCodes = {
                code: stocks,
                price: stockPrices[index],
                orderType: (urls.buy.includes(alertName) ? 'BUY' : 'WATCH'),
                target: await setSellPrice(stockPrices[index], 1),
                stopLoss: await setStopLoss(stockPrices[index], 1),
            }
            return stockCodes;
        }
    })

    return STOCKS;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

After reading the async/await part, I was wondering there is nothing wrong with the way how async/await is used & `STOCKS` must be returned with expected values. So, I setup a simulation as follows & ran the code.

```
async function setSellPrice(price) { return new Promise(function resolver(resolve) {setTimeout(function someTimeLater() { resolve(price)});}); }
async function setStopLoss(price) { return new Promise(function resolver(resolve) {setTimeout(function someTimeLater() { resolve(price)});}); }
const data = { stocks: 'A,B,C'. trigger_prices: '100,120,140', alert_name: 'XYZ' };
let result = await prepareStocks(data);
```

And got `STOCKS` not defined error.

Your code was correct in terms of how `async/await` works. The problem with the original code was, the `STOCKS` variable was not defined. I am assuming, it was not defined anywhere else. So, doing the following works as expected.

```
let result = await prepareStocks(data);

async function prepareStocks(incomingStocks) { 
    const STOCKS = [];
    var stockCodes = incomingStocks.stocks.split(',');
    var stockPrices = incomingStocks.trigger_prices.split(',');
    var alertName = incomingStocks.alert_name;
    stockCodes.forEach(async(stocks, index) => {

        if (stockPrices[index] > 100) {

            var stockCodes = {
                code: stocks,
                price: stockPrices[index],
                orderType: (urls.buy.includes(alertName) ? 'BUY' : 'WATCH'),
                target: await setSellPrice(stockPrices[index], 1),
                stopLoss: await setStopLoss(stockPrices[index], 1),
            }
            STOCKS.push(stockCodes);
        }

    });
    return STOCKS;

}
```

Comment: Thanks for commenting. 
The variable was already declared in the code.It was not there in the code snippet which I have shared. The issue was `forEach` related. The code shared by @Brijesh worked fine.

Comment: Do you see `const STOCKS = [];` line in the code that I have shared? Could you try and see if that works? I am saying because, how you have written `async/await` is correct. I see no reason for it to not to work.